# Getting rid of absolute value bars to rewrite a linear program in standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convex-optimization, absolute-value

I'm attempting to reformulate a linear program into standard form. Part of this problem requires me to eliminate absolute values from all of my variables. Specifically, I have the problem: 
\begin{align*}
&\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^2} 2x_1 + 3|x_2-10|\\
&\text{Subject to } |x_1+2| + |x_2| \le 5
\end{align*}
I have determined the following:

Let $$x_2^+:=\max\{x_2-10,0\}$$

and

$$x_2^-:=\max\{-x_2+10,0\}$$

Then 
$$|x_2-10| = x_2^++x_2^- \text{ and } x_2-10 = x_2^+-x_2^-$$
Here, we note that $x_2^+, x_2^- \ge 0$.

> What I need is some way to express $|x_2|$ in terms of $x_2^+$ and $x_2^-$ that **doesn't use absolute value bars**.

I've tried several things on this front, but I keep getting stuck. Do I need to introduce more variables to make this work? Any hints or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I don't actually need to know the solution to this linear program.

Comment: The abolute value is a simple and useful concept. If you don't want to use it, you may find an alternative form which also works. However I expect that things only become more complicated. My advise is not to spend time and effort on this aspect of your program.

Comment: @M.Wind I agree that doing this for every question is overkill- But it's important for the OP to understand that linear programs with absolute values are still standard linear programs, and that the absolute values do not invalidate the linearity.

Comment: |x| = $\sqrt {x^2}$

Comment: @WilliamElliot while that is an interesting approach, I should have clarified that I need the problem to remain a linear program, so all of the constraints should remain linear too.

Comment: @BSplitter indeed you need to introduce more variables, one set per absolute value

Comment: @LinAlg will my new set of variables for $|x_2|$ be dependent on $x_2^+$ and $x_2^-$?

Comment: @BSplitter no, each new set is independent

Comment: @LinAlg Is there a way I can intuitively know that each new set should be independent? This seems really counterintuitive to me. Or do I just need to write an entire constraint that relates the two?

Comment: Naming a variable $x_2^+$ while it does not model $\max\{0,x_2\}$ is what is counterintuitive to me

Answer (score 2):

The first step is usually to introduce new variables, but with *inequalities*:
\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize} &&2x_1 + 3t_1\\
&\text{Subject to } &&t_2 + t_3 \le 5,\\
&&&|x_2-10|\le t_1,\\
&&&|x_1+2|\le t_2,\\
&&&|x_2|\le t_3.
\end{align*}
Note that the solution is the same (obviously an upper bound plus equalities are included).

The second step is to observe that e.g.
$$
|x_2-10|\le t_1\iff -t_1\le x_2-10\le t_1
$$
etc, that is each absolute value inequality can be replaced by two linear ones.

The price to pay: increased dimension.

The gain (?): linear programming software.